# Performing an action on individual arrays in array of arrays

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

I have an array of arrays and I want to be able to perform some cleanup on each array individually within the array of arrays.

Here are the two arrays:

```
x = [array([4, 1, 2, 0]), array([5])]

y = [array([ 0.6,  0.7,  0.8,  0.9]), array([ 0.4])]
```

I want to find the top, let's say, 50% of the y-array and apply the same cut to the x-array so the indices match up.

So in this case I would want it to return:

```
x = [array([2, 0], array([5])]

y = [array([0.8, 0.9], array([0.4])]
```

Is this possible?

Comment: what programming language? And what if the array is `array([4, 1, 2, 0, 5])` ?

Comment: Oh sorry, python. I had that array to begin with, I needed to split them up so I can perform an action on each set individually.